# Manual Sequence Number In MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, guid

I am trying to generate manual sequence number for our tables. We can't go for auto incremental number because we are using composite key on two columns and our application will run on cloud and also run independently on client premises without connectivity with cloud. And our data needs to sync with our cloud central db. As you know in auto increment case we didn't able to sync our data on cloud (because our application can run without cloud and in this case duplicate data should be found on cloud). Please share any procedure through which we can generate auto numbers. We are planning to write a function which will generate a unique number for our tables. Please guide us.

Please also guide us if number of users are getting a unique number from same table then how it will manage locking on table row level.

Comment: Personally, I'd use a GUID rather than a simple sequence number

Comment: `guid` tag added. Nice question by the way

Comment: I cannot see why a composite key prohibits the use of a surrogate. Even if the surrogate was a component of the composite, this would work fine in a MyISAM table

Comment: Please share more details. Why should "run on cloud" disallow the usage of auto increments?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you've effectively posted a (larger) syncing question in the garb of an Auto-Increment query... because any answer would invariably have counter questions surrounding things like disconnected operations, syncing, etc...

A point you may want to be concerned about is that the Sequence is effectively becoming 'data' and not meta-data as a sequence is supposed to be. By definition data becomes unchangeable without application awareness, and therefore you may want to revisit whether this way of 'syncing' data back from disconnected clients, has better alternatives.

Anyway, if creating your own sequence is inevitable, you should probably use a statically generated list of values generated by the central-backend that the clients download on a regular basis (probably during syncing previous day's data back to server). If not on a really high transaction rate, this in my experience has the least gotchas when trying to debug syncing issues.

Comment: how about guids like [This Article?](http://kccoder.com/mysql/uuid-vs-int-insert-performance/). I am not saying I know, but floating it out there for peeps to ponder :)

Comment: Since you tagged postgres, I was assuming you were looking for an agnostic solution. Anyway, yes MySQL's GUID may help, and am sorry don't have much experience with it. And although I am not sure if I correctly understand how would you sync the data with both generating (mostly unique) random IDs, but I guess you'd manage that somehow.

Comment: guid getting 36 bytes and integer getting 4 bytes..i believe integer performance is good than char. is it

Comment: In PostgreSQL, yes. Can't say much about MySQL though.